# Jupyter Octave Kernel Inline Graph Windows

Tags: windows, gnuplot, jupyter, octave

I recently installed the octave_kernel for jupyter notebooks. I also installed gnuplot, but I can't plot inline, this error message shows up:

> Inline plot failed, consider trying another graphics toolkit
> error: print: figure must be visible or qt toolkit must be used with **gl_window** property 'on' or QT_OFFSCREEN feature available
> error: called from
> _make_figures>safe_print at line 125 column 7
> _make_figures at line 49 column 13

I think the solution is in the configuration section of [this](https://github.com/Calysto/octave_kernel) page. However I'm not familiar with jupyter configuration and being on Windows doesn't help...
Can you guys help me out?

Comment: you probably need to have gnuplot on the path (as hinted here: https://pypi.org/project/octave-kernel/ )

Answer (score 4):

I think it has to do with **how the Octave Kernel connects jupyter to the program**, since I get the same error on the newest version of Octave.

Here is what I have discovered:

I have installed two versions of Octave both 32 bits.

- Octave 4.4.1 that was the one I used the most and
- Octave 6.1.0 that is the most recent one.

*I also have gnuplot 5.2 patch level 7 installed-

The octave kernel is installed in anaconda via:

`conda install octave_kernel`

- to know where to look for the executable in windows you require the enviromental variable, here i tell it to go for Octave-4.4.1:

`OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE` 
`C:\\Octave\\Octave-4.4.1\\bin\\octave-cli.exe`

once it's up and running, the jupyter notebook loads the kernel  and i run the example:

```
x=-10:0.1:10+eps;
y=-10:0.1:10+eps;

[xx,yy]=meshgrid(x,y);

zz= sin(sqrt(xx.^2+yy.^2))./(sqrt(xx.^2+yy.^2));

surf(xx,yy,zz)
view(-35,45)
shading interp
```

[resultant plotting from the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J5TS.png)

If I check the graphic toolkits that display the plots with the commands i get:

`available_graphics_toolkits()`

```
    ans =
    {
      [1,1] = fltk
      [1,2] = gnuplot
    }
```

And the current toolkit is:

`loaded_graphics_toolkits ()`

```
    ans =
    {
      [1,1] = gnuplot
    }
```

**BUT** if i change the enviromental variable to point to the Octave-6.1.0 executable with: `C:\\Octave\\Octave-6.1.0\\mingw32\\bin\\octave-cli.exe`

once i run the chunks of code, the ones with calculations are doing fine

```
x=-10:0.1:10+eps;
y=-10:0.1:10+eps;

[xx,yy]=meshgrid(x,y);

zz= sin(sqrt(xx.^2+yy.^2))./(sqrt(xx.^2+yy.^2));
```

for example, if i take the `;` off the zz variable you get the matrix printed on the output

```
zz =

 Columns 1 through 6:

   7.0710e-02   7.0912e-02   7.0764e-02   7.0268e-02   6.9428e-02   6.8251e-02
   7.0912e-02   7.0761e-02   7.0254e-02   6.9397e-02   6.8194e-02   6.6655e-02
   7.0764e-02   7.0254e-02   6.9386e-02   6.8166e-02   6.6601e-02   6.4702e-02
   7.0268e-02   6.9397e-02   6.8166e-02   6.6583e-02   6.4658e-02   6.2404e-02
   6.9428e-02   6.8194e-02   6.6601e-02   6.4658e-02   6.2378e-02   5.9773e-02
   6.8251e-02   6.6655e-02   6.4702e-02   6.2404e-02   5.9773e-02   5.6826e-02 ...

 .... etc.
```

but the plot block of code

```
surf(xx,yy,zz)
view(-35,45)
shading interp
```

sends as output the error:

```
Inline plot failed, consider trying another graphics toolkit
error: print: figure must be visible or qt toolkit must be used with __gl_window__ property 'on' or QT_OFFSCREEN feature available
error: called from
    _make_figures>safe_print at line 125 column 7
    _make_figures at line 49 column 13
```

Which tells me **the jupyter kernel isn't working completely** with Octave 6.1.0.

I know Octave 6.1.0 is working because the same code produces the correct plot if you run it directly in the octave application gui or cli.

[plot window of the same graph captured from the Octave-gui application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCYl7.png)

---

The octave kernel says it's working if I check it with the command

`python -m octave_kernel.check`

The check reveals:

```
Octave kernel v0.32.0
metakernel v0.27.5
Python v3.78.56 <default, Sep  4 2020, 00:03:40> [MSC v.1916 32 bit <intel>]
Python path: C:\Users\myuser\anaconda3\python.exe

Conecting to Octave...
PS C:\Users\myuser> Can't load 'C:\Users\myuser\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\metakernel\magics\shell_magic.py' : error <pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x033C3178>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compiler<'>'>
<pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x033C3178>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compiler<'>'>
Octave conection established
Octave kernel v0.32.0 running GNU Octave v6.1.0
Graphics toolkit: fltk
available toolkits: [1,1] = fltk
    [1,2] = gnuplot
>
```

when trying to plot in the jupyter notebook  the console keeps sending a similar error

```
PS C:\Users\myuser> [MetaKernelApp] ERROR : Can't load 'C:\Users\myuser\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\metakernel\magics\shell_magic.py' : error <pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x0341C718>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compiler<'>'>
<pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x0341C718>
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compiler<'>'>
```

That seems to be affiliated with accessing  the magic.py file in the metakernel package, when plotting.

i think i'm gonna fill an issue at github to see what can be done about this error.

Comment: I get the same exact errors as you. I gave up and use the Linux subsystem. In 5 minutes I got everything working.

Comment: @Johnson can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

you are not wrong doing.

https://wiki.octave.org/Recap_of_the_hierarchy_of_each_plot_element

please add this line your script and it works.

```
graphics_toolkit ("gnuplot");
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding `set(gcf,'Visible','on')` at the end of the plotting cell helps. For a discussion on the issue see [fox serie's issue report](https://github.com/Calysto/octave_kernel/issues/183). I guess it is better to downgrade octave to v5.2.0 until octave_kernel is updated to support octave v6.

Comment: This works for me. Great suggestion!